# Making a variable in a linear program be equal to a ramp function

Tags: linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming, linearization

In a linear program, I have a variable $y$ that must obey $y=\max(x-a,0)$ where $x$ is a linear combination of the other variables and $a$ is a constant. $x$ and $y$ and $a$ are always non-negative.

If the objective function decreases w.r.t. $y$, then adding the constraint $y\geq x-a$ makes it work.

Are there any way to add dummy varibles and contraints such that $y=\max(x-a,0)$ when the objective function increases w.r.t. $y$? I can't say $y\leq x-a$ because if $x-a<0$ it contradicts the non-negativity of $y$ whereby the solution might no longer be in the feasible region or the problem might even be infeasible.

Comment: This would make your problem non-convex, so it's not representable in linear programming.  You can do this in integer linear programming by adding a binary variable and some constraints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\bar{x} > a$ be a (small) constant upper bound on $x$.  (If $\bar{x} \le a$, then $y=0$ always.) Introduce a binary variable $z$ and linear constraints
\begin{align}
y &\ge x - a \tag1 \\
y &\ge 0 \tag2 \\
y - x + a &\le a z \tag3 \\
y &\le (\bar{x}-a) (1-z) \tag4 \\
\end{align}
Constraints $(1)$ and $(2)$ enforce $y \ge \max(x-a,0)$.
Constraint $(3)$ enforces $z=0 \implies y \le x-a$.
Constraint $(4)$ enforces $z=1 \implies y \le 0$.